# Windows 7 EFI Partition Deleted

Tags: windows-7, boot, uefi

I converted my Windows 7 GPT disk to dynamic, which resulted in it being unable to boot. So I used EaseUs Partition Master on my second Win 7 installation to convert the disk back to basic. Now, I have one partition, which is my C: drive, and I can't figure out how to recovery my EFI partition. I no longer see the "Windows" entry in my EFI boot menu. The Windows 7 repair on the install DVD doesn't see my installation. Please let me know how to restore the EFI partition.

Comment: What tool was used to convert W7 GPT disk to dynamic ? Do you have two disks connected - one GPT and one MBR ?